# create a collection of unique dictionaries

Tags: c#

I would like to create multiple dictionaries that have a `Guid` as a key and `x` as a value where `x` has to implement the interface `IComponent`.

All these dictionaries should be stored in a collection that throws an exception when a dictionary of componentType `x` gets added but already exists.

I am not sure if I have to create this dictionary and the collection on my own or if I can use something. So the dictionary itself would be

`MyDict<T> : Dictionary<Guid, T> where T : IComponent`

but I think I can solve this problem with a `KeyedByTypeCollection`.

```
    private KeyedByTypeCollection<Dictionary<Guid, IComponent>> componentPools = new KeyedByTypeCollection<Dictionary<Guid, IComponent>>();

    public Dictionary<Guid, T> GetComponentPool<T>() where T : IComponent
    {
        return componentPools[typeof(T)]; // not working
    }

    public void AddComponentPool<T>() where T : IComponent
    {
        componentPools.Add(new Dictionary<Guid, T>()); // not working
        // other stuff
    }

    public void RemoveComponentPool<T>() where T : IComponent
    {
        componentPools.Remove(typeof(T)); // this works
        // other stuff
    }
```

This example comes up with two problemes

- `GetComponentPool`: Cannot implicitly convert `IComponent` to `T`
- `AddComponentPool`: Cannot convert from `T` to `IComponent`

Is it possible to fix the code or is the use of `KeyedByTypeCollection<Dictionary<Guid, IComponent>>` not possible anyways?

Comment: Given that you want the type of the value to be based on the type of the key you're going to need to write your own collection (which can use a dictionary internally of course).

Comment: where is your class full code ?

Comment: Dictionary<Guid, T> is not of type Dictionary<Guid, IComponent> even if T implements IComponent. So you can not add Collection<Guid, T> to a Collection that is declared as Collection<Dictionary<Guid, IComponent>>. This will not work at all.
You can define an untyped Collection and cast the items in your  accessor methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
         public class MyDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
            {
                public Type ContainingType { get; set; }
            }

          public class MyStrangerList
            {
                private readonly List<MyDictionary<Guid, IComponent>> _componentPools = new List<MyDictionary<Guid, IComponent>>();

                public MyDictionary<Guid, IComponent> GetComponentPool<T>() where T : IComponent
                {
                    return _componentPools.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ContainingType == typeof(T));
                }

                public void AddComponentPool<T>() where T : IComponent
                {
                    var currentPool = GetComponentPool<T>();
                    if (currentPool == null)
                    {
                        var mydictionary = new MyDictionary<Guid, IComponent> { ContainingType = typeof(T) };
                        _componentPools.Add(mydictionary);
                    }
                }

                public void RemoveComponentPool<T>() where T : IComponent
                {
                    var currentPool = GetComponentPool<T>();
                    if (currentPool != null)
                    {
                        _componentPools.Remove(currentPool);
                    }
                }
            }


    private void Usage()
    {
        var myStrangerList = new MyStrangerList();

        myStrangerList.AddComponentPool<TextBox>(); //add
        myStrangerList.AddComponentPool<ComboBox>(); //add
        myStrangerList.AddComponentPool<ListBox>(); //add
        myStrangerList.AddComponentPool<CheckBox>(); //add
        myStrangerList.AddComponentPool<TextBox>(); //duplicate not added
        myStrangerList.RemoveComponentPool<ListBox>(); //remove

        var textBoxPool = myStrangerList.GetComponentPool<TextBox>();
        if (textBoxPool != null)
        {
            var textBox1 = new TextBox();
            var textBox2 = new TextBox();
            var textBox3 = new TextBox();
            textBoxPool.Add(Guid.NewGuid(), textBox1);
            textBoxPool.Add(Guid.NewGuid(), textBox2);
            textBoxPool.Add(Guid.NewGuid(), textBox3);
        }
    }
```